# Как узнать, пересекаются ли регулярные выражения?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Например, есть такая регулярка

Принимает только одну цифру:

```
/([0-9]{,1})/
```

А есть такая, принимает от 2 до 3 цифр

```
/([0-9]{2,3})/
```

Они никогда не пересекутся, то, что одна будет считать истиной никогда не станет истиной для другой

Но есть такой вариант:

```
/([0-9]{2,3})/
/([a-z0-1]{1,3})/
```

И они пересекаются как только во второй будет от 2 до 3 цифр: 00, 01, 10, 11

Comment: Кстати первая регулярка вообще неправильная никаких совпадений не будет.

Comment: Если хотите что-то хитрое то вам нужно распарсить само регулярное выражение и написать логику когда пересечение случится а когда нет. Более простой способ: проверить строку на эти 2 регулярки

Comment: Вы, вероятно, пытаетесь решить проблему неверными средствами. Такой трэш я даже не знаю где применить, т. к. вариантов больше нет.

Comment: Ну, я просто хочу чтобы роутеры у модулей не конфликтовали

Comment: а как они могут конфликтовать? и от куда у модели роутер?

Comment: Модуль, не модель. Например, один программист сделал для системы модуль новостей который занимает адрес /news/ и другой программист сделал модуль который тоже занимает этот адрес. Юзер установил эти 2 модуля и у него конфликты могут вылезать неожиданно. Пока все легко отследить, но что если модуль новостей по адресу /news/ будет выдавать последние новости, а модуль пользователей по адресу /{username}/ профили и кто-то зарегает профиль "news"? А что если роутер сложней и уже совсем не легко отследить?

Answer (score 0):

Для корректного построения операций над множествами следует определиться с  юниверсумом, т. е. с множеством допустимых элементов. И это не схоластика, поскольку без юниверсума возникают трудности с операцией дополнения (отрицания) множеств, что актуально и для регулярных выражений.

При этом всегда можно проверить "пересечение регулярных выражений" путём перебора по юниверсуму (или его тестовому подмножеству - на ограниченном алфавите или с  ограниченной длиной выражений), хотя в несложных случаях можно обойтись логикой.